# Conference paper published in journal

Tags: journals, conference, paper-submission

I want to know that's it is written on some conference website that paper will be published at Scopus indexed journal. What that means. Is that paper is considered a conference paper or journal paper after publishing.?
Thanks

Comment: Typically this would still be a conference paper, but can you share the web page? It would make it easier to verify what is being offered.

Comment: Please check this [link](http://icebehi.poltekkesdepkes-sby.ac.id/)

Comment: The linked website looks rather dubious: _Accepted, presented and selected papers will be submitted for uploading to Journal of Physics: Conference Series (IOP Publishing), Lecture Notes in Electrical Engineering (Springer Verlag), and Materials Science Forum..._ Firstly, three venues are listed. Secondly, it mentions only _selected papers_. Thirdly, the term _uploading_ is used, rather than _publishing_.

Comment: Regarding your question, rather than _published at Scopus indexed journal_ I think you mean _indexed by SCOPUS_.

Comment: what is the difference between uploading and publishing?

Comment: @TalhaAnwar Well, _submitted for uploading_ or _submitted for publishing_ are both problematic. The word _submitted_ weakens the notion. Getting back to your question: _Published_ has an understood meaning to academics, _uploaded_ does not.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give a specific example of a fairly high-ranking robotics journal (no affiliation). [Robotics and Automation Letters (RA-L)](https://www.ieee-ras.org/publications/ra-l) is a recently-started journal of the Robotics and Automation Society, which is coupled with flagship robotics conferences (IEEE International Conference on Robotics and Automation (ICRA), the IEEE Conference on Automation Science and Engineering (CASE), and the IEEE/RSJ International Conference on Intelligent Robots and Systems (IROS)).

Since it has only started in 2016, the impact factor (JCR Impact Factor of 3.6 for 2019) is so-so amongst established journals, but in my opinion really high for a relatively young journal.

Publication in RA-L when coupled with the above three conferences (IROS, ICRA, CASE) works like this:

- When submitting to a conference, you have an *option* to submit the paper for RA-L special issue in addition
- RA-L special issue deadline tends to be 2-3 weeks prior the conference submission deadline
- Technically, the journal submission could be rejected while the paper is still accepted for conference presentation and publication in conference proceedings (but I haven't heard of that actually happening)
- If accepted to RA-L, the paper will still be presented in conference sessions, but will be indexed as part of RA-L special issue associated to that conference.